# How to push all objects in class into one array javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop

I'm trying to make language learn app and i have a problem. I have class "Word"

```
class Word {
    constructor(englishWord, polishWord){
       this.englishWord = englishWord
       this.polishWord = polishWord
       this.displayTranslation = () =>{
          console.log(`${englishWord} = ${polishWord}`)
       }
    }
}
```

and lots of objects like

```
const intimate = new Word('intimate', 'intymny/prywatny')
const insurance = new Word('insurance', 'ubezpieczenie')
```

and I honestly don't have idea how to push all objects into one array. Can I use 'foreach' on every class object? Or is there a better solution for this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. Why would you need an array instead of some kind of `WordManager` class that is responsible for building and recording words, a la `class WordManager { constructor() {} create(word, mapping) { let w = new Word(word, mapping); this.words.push(w); return w; }`, or better yet, why not make a word dictionary instead of using individual word instances? Especially given that JS objects are already dictionaries: `const words = {}; words["intimate"] = "intymny/prywatny";` and take it from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's build up your problem in natural language before we write some code:

> A `Word` has its nativ and translation. A `Word` is stored in a `Dictionary`. You can add translations to a `Dictionary` and so on..

For that the `array` would be hide in a `Dictionary` like

```
class Dictionary {
    constructor() {
        this.words = []
    }

    addTranslation(word) {
        this.words.push(word)
    }

    // more ..
}
```

### Code Snippet

```js
class Word {
  constructor(englishWord, polishWord) {
    this.englishWord = englishWord
    this.polishWord = polishWord
    this.displayTranslation = () => {
      console.log(`${englishWord} = ${polishWord}`)
    }
  }
}

class Dictionary {
  constructor() {
    this.words = []
  }
  
  addTranslation(word) {
    this.words.push(word)
  }
  
  print() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.words.length; i++) {
      this.words[i].displayTranslation()
    }
  }
  
}


const dictionary = new Dictionary()

const intimate = new Word('intimate', 'intymny/prywatny')
const insurance = new Word('insurance', 'ubezpieczenie')

dictionary.addTranslation(intimate)
dictionary.addTranslation(insurance)

dictionary.print()
```

## Improvement

I suggest to use a `Map` instead of an `Array`. If the `Dictionary` will be extended by methods for finding words than you have to find the words in an `Array` by your self..

```js
class Word {
  constructor(englishWord, polishWord) {
    this.englishWord = englishWord
    this.polishWord = polishWord
    this.displayTranslation = () => {
      console.log(`${englishWord} = ${polishWord}`)
    }
  }
}

class Dictionary {
  constructor() {
    this.words = {}
  }
  
  addTranslation(word) {
    this.words[word.englishWord] = word.polishWord
  }
  
  getTranslation(english) {
    return this.words[english]
  }
  
  
  print() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.words.length; i++) {
      this.words[i].displayTranslation()
    }
  }
  
}


const dictionary = new Dictionary()
const intimate = new Word('intimate', 'intymny/prywatny')

dictionary.addTranslation(intimate)

console.log(dictionary.getTranslation('intimate'))
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to declare a global array where all instances will be pushed to

```
const instances = [];

class Word {
    constructor(englishWord, polishWord){
        this.englishWord = englishWord;
        this.polishWord = polishWord;
        this.displayTranslation = () =>{
           console.log(`${englishWord} = ${polishWord}`);
        };
        instances.push(this);
    }

    static GetWords() {
        instances.forEach( x => {
            x.displayTranslation();
        });
    }       
}

new Word('intimate', 'intymny/prywatny');
new Word('insurance', 'ubezpieczenie');

Word.GetWords();
```

Comment: Thank you! That's it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can push class objects into an Array without any issue:

```
// using your class declared above
const intimate = new Word('intimate', 'intymny/prywatny')
var array = [];
array.push(intimate);
```

But depending on your needs, you could put something like this directly into the constructor and have it collect all of the items it's constructed for you:

```
const instances = [];
class Word {
    constructor(englishWord, polishWord){
        this.englishWord = englishWord
        this.polishWord = polishWord
        this.displayTranslation = () =>{
            console.log(`${englishWord} = ${polishWord}`)
        }
        Word.addInstance(this);
    }
    static addInstance(item){
        instances.push(item);
    }
    static getInstances(){
        return instances;
    }
    static clearInstances(){
        instances.length = 0;
    }
}
```

With this every time you construct an instance it's added to the external array. If you need to get everything from the array you can call `Word.getInstances()` or `Word.clearInstances()` if you want to empty it.